# JRE with smallest possible file size

Tags: java

I am currently working on a game engine for Java, with compile targets for windows, macos, linux, android and the web. Now I have a question about deploying to windows, macos and linux.

My original plan was to use [packr](https://github.com/libgdx/packr) (An application that takes a JAR-file and any JRE and creates a binary) and a copy of the *Amazon Corretto JRE* to create the binaries. My problem with this is the file size: A simple "Hello, World" on Windows already requires ~100MB disk space...

I would really like to include the JRE inside the application (so no wrapper that downloads the JRE if needed). Is there maybe some JRE out there that is optimized for smallest code size or maybe some way to generate one according to my dependencies?

Comment: Newer versions of the JDK contain a tool, the `jpackage` tool, to create a custom JRE package, containing only the modules that your application needs. Maybe that's useful: [Packaging Tool User Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/jpackage/packaging-overview.html). It's part of the standard JDK, so no third-party software needed, which is also an advantage.

Comment: For minimal size jlink is the way to go. You can use it to build minimal JRE with just the modules you need for your specific application.

Comment: I'll have a look at jlink

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to [nur1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9046497/nur1), I have now figured out a solution. Using OpenJDK version 11, I can build my Program, use *jdeps* to figure out what parts of the default JRE my application needs and create a custom JRE that only includes the required classes. The whole process is also described [here](https://blog.adoptium.net/2021/10/jlink-to-produce-own-runtime/).

A custom JRE configured for a simple "Hello, World!" now takes up ~25MB, which I can definitely live with.